# Tenosrflow RandomForest 'TensorForestEstimator' Example predict() and score() throws no atrribute error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to run a random forest example using in tensorflow 'TensorForestEstimator'. Following is the code that I used from tensorflow git repo:

[Github Code Link](http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/random_forest_mnist.py)

Error I am getting:

File "/home/mckw9/tensorflow2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 1363, in score
    eval_results, global_step = self._estimator._evaluate_model(

AttributeError: 'TensorForestEstimator' object has no attribute '_evaluate_model'

I am using tensorflow-gpu 1.0.1, NVIDIA Titan X Pascal 12GB GDDR5X, Ubuntu 14.04, Python 3.4

Comment: It's worth noting that TensorForestEstimator won't use the GPU.  Random forest training doesn't have a good opportunity to make use of them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappears for Tensorflow 1.1+.

Comment: I face this problem even in Tensorflow 1.1

Comment: Try the latest build.  According to the current code in github (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/client/random_forest.py), TensorForestEstimator inherits from estimator.Estimator (which has _evaluate_model).  So there's no way an AttributeError like that would happen.